# debugging a crash (c++)

Tags: visual-c++, windows-services

I am having a service which calls a C++ COM dll. The C++ COM dll causes some problem and the service crashes.

I couldn't figure it at what point the service crash. I used debugdiag. But it is not putting any crash dump.

Kindly let me know how I can debug a application crash. Or direct me to some good tutorials and tools.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the Visual Studio debugger to your service via **Tools / Attach to process**.  You might need to check **Show processes from all users** in order to see your service in the list.

Comment: The service is in .Net 2.0. But the COM dll is from VC6. I couldn't find Attach to process in VC6. Whether attach to process in VS2008 shall work?

Comment: I don't have VC6 here, but is it **Build > Start Debug > Attach to Process**?  Or attaching using a later version of Visual Studio ought to work fine.

Comment: Yes :D. Its there. I will try it. Thanks Richie.

Comment: @Jai - If you have any later version of Visual Studio, attach using that.  The debugging environment is much richer.